# Hotfix 2600100 won't install despite meeting Prerequisites

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, hotfix

I've added this on serverfault @ https://serverfault.com/questions/495419/hotfix-2600100-wont-install-despite-meeting-prerequisites but haven't got any replies so reposting here:

I'm trying to install a Microsoft Hotfix (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100) on a Win Server 2k8 box which has .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 installed, but its telling me

None of the products that are affected by this install would be affected

All prerequisites have been met, and it works on other Wind Server 2k8 boxes which have .Net 2.0 Framework and .Net 3.5 Framework installed separately. Has anyone encountered something like this before

Comment: Sounds to me like the update is either already installed or you have a later version of .NET that includes the hotfix.

Comment: The hotfix hasn't been applied. Information on the issue is here (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx). The box in question suffers from the bug and the browser definition files are out of date. It has .Net 3.5 SP1 and .Net 4 installed. The hotfix for 4.0 runs ok but the one for .Net 2.0 SP2/.Net 3.5 SP1 doesn't and gives the above error. Checking prerequisites all is installed that needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft have released a new hotifx for .NET Framework 2.0 - Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 (CBS) on the aforementioned page (http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2600100&kbln=en-us) which now works.

Answer (score 0):

The new release mentioned above seems to be a .msu format. Is there a .exe format?